# Table of contents alignment problem with multi-line \pbox in \includepdf's addtotoc

Tags: table-of-contents, boxes, pdfpages

I'm inserting many 1-page PDF's that I also include in the table of contents.

The only issue I have is with the alignment of my entry with the toc counter for PDF # and it's corresponding page number. They are centered on the multiline `\pbox` I've used in the `\includepdf`'s `addtotoc`.

[image]
The following code illustrates my problem, I need the multi-line entries to have the page numbering and counter aligned with the first line (as the single line entry looks).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pbox}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, addtotoc={1,subsubsection,3,\pbox{20cm}{\textbf{Abstract Author}, One line title with no alignment issues},chap:samplepdf1}]{}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, addtotoc={1,subsubsection,3,\pbox{20cm}{\textbf{Abstract Author}, Two line title with alignment issues\\ Two line title with alignment issues},chap:samplepdf2}]{}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, addtotoc={1,subsubsection,3,\pbox{20cm}{\textbf{Abstract Author}, Three line title with alignment issues\\ Three line title with alignment issues \\ Three line title with alignment issues},chap:samplepdf3}]{}
\end{document}
```

Maybe there is some way to insert multiple line breaks that will work? Maybe the packages are still buggy and no known fix? Would rather not start from scratch again!

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer `varwidth` to `pbox`. A top aligned box is necessary, with some compensation for the excess depth when the box contains more than one line.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\vw}[1]{%
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth}\strut#1\unskip\nobreak\strut\par
  \end{varwidth}%
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\setlength\lineskip{0pt}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\includepdf[
  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},
  addtotoc={
    1,
    subsubsection,
    3,
    \vw{\textbf{Abstract Author}, One line title with no alignment issues},
    chap:samplepdf1
  }
]{pyk}

\includepdf[
  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},
  addtotoc={
    1,
    subsubsection,
    3,
    \vw{\textbf{Abstract Author}, Two line title with alignment issues\\
        Two line title with alignment issues},
    chap:samplepdf2}
]{pyk}

\includepdf[
  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},
  addtotoc={
    1,
    subsubsection,
    3,
    \vw{\textbf{Abstract Author}, Three line title with alignment issues\\
        Three line title with alignment issues \\
        Three line title with alignment issues},
    chap:samplepdf3
  }
]{pyk}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the find and replace command for "\pbox{20cm}" to "\vw" for my entire document completely fixed all alignment issues in my table of contents AND made all my table entries better.

Thank you egreg!